# Azure DevOps: build agent installed in custom image

Tags: azure-devops

We need to set up a scale set for build agents in Azure, and we are facing the following situation: after creating the custom image of the VM in which we have installed the build agent, the agentId needs to be updated. We have checked the parameters for Agent.Listener.exe, but nowhere is to be found a parameter like "re-register" or so.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent

Comment: @devopsdina yeah, I did, but I still do not see it: I would like to re-use all existing parameters (authentication, url, etc.), and only re-register the agent. If not, I need to include, on the script that would do this when booting, all authentication parameters :-/

Comment: I am afraid there is no such parameter like "re-register", we may need to write the script that would do this when booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to wait a bit. Seems that our problem was not specific as it could seem and Microsoft was already working on a possible solution "Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set Agents". The image used by the scale set does not contain the agent, and it gets installed when a new VM on the scale set gets instantiated.